# equivalence of two continuity definitions

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  ($X\subseteq \mathbb R$)
I have the following two definitions for continuity (I am working in a constructive setting so I have some restrictions on the standard definitions):
1. the $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition: $\forall a \in X \forall \varepsilon>0\exists \delta >0\forall x\in X (|x-a|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon)$
2. For every open set $V$ in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f^{-1}[V]=U\cap X$ **and U is small**.

The property of U being "small" is somewhat complex but it is somewhat equivalent to U being countable (or more precisely, U being in $J_2$ from Jensen hierarchy).

I wish to prove that they are equivalent.
I think I managed to show that $(2\Rightarrow 1)$.
However, for $(1\Rightarrow 2)$ I believe I need an additional assumption that is the separability of $X$. The argument goes as follow:
For any $c\in f^{-1}[V]$ there exists $\varepsilon >0$ s.t. $B_\varepsilon (f(c))\subseteq V$ (since V is open). By $(1)$ there exists $\delta_c$ s.t. $f[B_{\delta_c} \cup X]\subseteq B_\varepsilon (f(c))\subseteq V$. Thus, for any $c\in f^{-1}[V]$, $B_{\delta_c} \cup X\subseteq f^{-1}[B_\varepsilon (f(c))]\subseteq f^{-1}[V]$.
Then, take $U$ to be $\cup_{c\in f^{-1}[V]\cap D}B_{\delta_c}(c)$ where D is a dense subset in of X.   I took the intersection with D since other wise the union is not necessarily "small".
The thing is that I cannot seem to prove that $f^{-1}[V]\subseteq U\cap X$. Is there some argument I am missing, or is my choice for $U$ is simply wrong?  Also, am I using here some choice axiom for picking the $\delta_c$? Thank a lot for your help!

Comment: Where did you take the second deffinition from? $U$ is a subset of $R$ but $X$ does not need to be a subset of $R$ so probably your intersection is empty. Note that continuity depends on the topologies you are considering for $X$ and $R$. I think you won't have any problem if you change the second definition for this one: "for every open set $V$ in $R$, it is the case that $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set in $X$"

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to mention that X is a subset of R. I corrected it now. Do you think that in this case my argument is correct?